# Change the commandbutton label on click and keeping that on submit

Tags: jsf, label, commandbutton

I have a command button

```
<h:commandButton class="go" id="flashwareSelectBUTTON"  value="Show" action="#{currentCompatibilityRow.selectFlashwareItem}" onclick="changeLabel(this);">
```

I want to change the text of button to "Hide" on click, the function is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeLabel(buttonLabel) {

        if (buttonLabel.value=="Show")
           buttonLabel.value="Hide"
        else
                     buttonLabel.value="Show"       
    } 

</script>
```

The problem is that the label is changed to "Hide" for a fraction of seconds. It should stay till I press the button again. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi BalusC, canyou suggest something ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is because, your javascript is changing the label successfully but your `h:commandButton` is getting re-rendered after action is complete.
One way is to use `f:ajax` and submit your `h:form` through ajax. If you do this then changes from your Javascript wont reset after action is complete.

```
<h:commandButton value="Show" onclick="changeLabel(this);" ...>
     <f:ajax/>
</h:commandButton>
```

If that doesn't work then Second solution is:
You could get `value` from `ManagedBean` also.

```
<h:commandButton value="#{managedBean.btnTxt}" ... />
```

You also need to use Javascript along with that, because `onclick` will be called before your action method get completed.
So you will have to change the value from javascript for `onclick` and also change the value `btnTxt` at the end of action method to stay unchanged even after `h:form` submit and button gets re-rendered.